# Is it possible to know which input gate triggered the handleMessage() method of Omnet++?

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

I have a simple network in Omnet++ where lower levels of the network are received in one in gate (*inLower*) and same-level network data is retrieved in another in gate (*inMid*).

I am using the handleMessage() method of Omnet++ to trigger some action upon receiving a message. Is there any way to distinguish which input gate received the message? I know that I can specify which output gate a message is sent through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the arrival gate for a given [`cMessage`](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cMessage.html) by using [`cMessage::getArrivalGate()`](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cMessage.html#a6980409d333e9770e3157a6b68153b52).

```cpp
void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
    cGate *arrivalGate = msg->getArrivalGate();
    if (arrivalGate == gate("inMid")) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // or y'know
    }
}
```

The example above assumes `inMid` is the string identifier for a scalar gate. If your gate is a vector gate you can first check if it has any gates (`gateSize("inMid") > 0`), then acquire its base gate (`cGate inMidBaseGate = gate("inMid", 0);`). You could then get its base id (`auto inMidBaseId = inMidBaseGate.getBaseId()`) which you could compare to the arrival gate and its base ID (`inMidBaseId == arrivalGate->getBaseId()`).

Comment: This works well for scalar gates; however, I am getting an error for vector gates: "No gate index specified when accessing vector gate". How can I specify this index to fix the error and how can I make it so that it doesn't matter what index it comes from?

Comment: Ah, your gate called `inMid` is a vector gate? You may use `cGate::getBaseId()` and compare that with `cMessage::getArrivalGate()->getBaseId` to check it for any of the gates part of your vector gate.